# Problem with position absolute in ie7, div moves 10px to the right

Tags: css, position, positioning, absolute, internet-explorer-7

ive got a problem on my position absolute property on IE7. My div moves 10px to the right. Below is my code. IE8 and 9 works fine. 
**id menu** is the div Im referring.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
body{margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;}
#holder{width: 400px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto;}
#left{float: left; width: 50px; height: 500px; background-color: red;}
#center{float: left; width: 300px; height: 500px; background-color: green;}
#right{float: left; width: 50px; height: 500px; background-color: red;}
#header{width: 300px; height: 70px; background-color: yellow;}
#gal-holder{width: 280px; height: 70px; margin: 0 auto;}
#gallery{width: 280px; height: 410px; background-color: orange;}
#button{width: 400px; height: 45px; background-color: red; margin: 0 auto;}
#menu{width: 300px; height: 45px; background-color: pink; position: absolute; z-index: 1000; top: 100px;}
#content{width: 380px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: blue; padding: 10px; color: #fff;}
#clear{height: 10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="holder">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="menu"></div>
        <div id="gal-holder">
            <div id="clear"></div>
            <div id="gallery"></div>
            <div id="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="content">Sample text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to `#center` and then `left:0px` to `#menu`.

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to their closest positioned parent. It's best to give the items you want to position a left/right and top/bottom coordinate to prevent weird results like the one you found.

Comment: @Galen..thank you very much galen. Now i can move on. Sadly i cant vote your answer coz i still have 11 reputation. Thanks again.

Comment: @ mu is too short...thanks, already done it and yours too. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @mu is too short..ok so i can only choose one answer. Sorry for my ignorance. =)

Answer (score 7):

You should specify both the top and left positions and add `position:relative` to the immediate parent:

```
#center {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: green;
    position:relative;
}
#menu { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: pink;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
}
```

And a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vRJMd/

The default `left` is `auto` and that more or less means that the browser can do whatever it thinks is sensible. Also, absolutely positioned elements are positioned with respect to the nearest ancestor with a position that is not `static` (which is probably `<body>` in your case).

Comment: .thanks, both you galen have solved my problem. My apologizes i cant vote of your answer coz i still have 11 reputation. Thank again.