# jquery dialog button not showing until hovering over it ie7

Tags: jquery, html, css

As the title suggests I'm having some IE7 problems. the problem I have right now is that my dialog doesn't work correctly.
Well, the dialog itself works, but the button on it doesn't show up. that is, until I hover on where it is actually placed.

Here's the jquery code

```
$('#sessionTimeout-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
            buttons: [{

                // Button one - closes dialog and makes call to keep-alive URL
                text: o.stayConnected,
                "class": "confirmSession",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    $('#sessionTimeout-dialog div div button').addClass('confirm');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: o.keepAliveUrl
                    });
                    $('.formOverlay').find('*').attr('disabled', false);

                    // Stop redirect timer and restart warning timer
                    controlRedirTimer('stop');
                    controlDialogTimer('start');
                }
            }]
        });
```

As this does work correctly with IE8 and up, FF and Chrome, I'm starting to think this is an issue that IE7 has with the  control generated by the dialog.

So just to sumarize again:

IE8+ work

IE7 has the following behaviour:

with class = "confirmSession"

1. page loads
2. no javascript errors
3. dialog shows up without button
4. I hover over the spot where the button should be
5. The button magically shows up with the correct css style.

without class = "confirmSession"

1. page loads
2. no javascript errors
3. dialog shows up with button (no css since it doesn't have a css class)

As I'm baffled by this behaviour, I hope we can work it out together.

EDIT:

As requested: my css style for the confirmSession class; It's taken from out .less file.

```
.confirmSession {
            width:45%; font-size: 1em; background: #4c8cb4 !IMPORTANT; border: #427594 1px solid; padding: 0px;  color: #fff; text-decoration: none; .box-sizing(border-box); white-space: normal; cursor: pointer; float: none; font-weight: 400; margin: 10px 2%; display: block; float: left;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4), 2px 2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4),2px 2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4), 2px 2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            text-align: center; position: absolute; bottom: 1em; left: 10px; right: 10px; 
        }
```

Comment: can u show the confirmSession class styles

Comment: I have added the css as you requested

Comment: IE7. In IE8+, FF and Chrome it works without any problems at all.

Comment: remove all the css properties  and then try to add one by one.Then we can find out the problem

Comment: It appears that position: absolute; on my last line is breaking it. Removing that makes my button go crazy with width and positioning, but it does show up on load.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100998/problem-with-position-absolute-in-ie7-div-moves-10px-to-the-right

Comment: Thanks to your help I was able to find my problem. I have removed position: absolute; bottom: 1em; left: 10px; right: 10px; and instead did $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').css("float", "none"); in my jquery script. This worked so far. Do hope I won't be using any more dialogs that need a right float though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever the styles you are used in  confirmSession  class are overriden by the jQuery styles.

So use `!important` before your styles.

Remove all the css properties and then try to add one by one.Then we can find out the problem

Comment: I have added my css to the opening post. I tried !important on my background, but that didn't work.

Comment: Gave you an upvote here because I was able to figure it out thanks to you. For those reading: my problem was with position: absolute. I have removed position: absolute; bottom: 1em; left: 10px; right: 10px; and instead did $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').css("float", "none"); in my jquery script.